# Looking for a consolidated datasheet for commonly used transitors

Tags: transistors, datasheet

I found it challenging to look for individual transistor pdf datasheets with somehow different layout styles then extract common parameters. Is there any consolidated datasheet or table that lists the essential parameters for common transistors? I came across this table in an article ( https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/transistor-basics ), and I found it very useful.

[image]

I am hoping to find something similar for a broader list of transistors.

Comment: You can use the selection tables on Digikey. Or at one of the major manufactures of jelly beans, like On Semi or Diodes Inc. Or break out your favorite spreadsheet program and make your own to capture the specific kinds of parts you're most interested in.

Comment: go to bottom of this page and click `download table` 
  ... first change results per page to 500 ... https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-bipolar-bjt-single/276?FV=-8%7C276&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25

Comment: Got my answer. Exactly what I was looking for. Thnk you jsotola and @ThePhoton Photon

Comment: On Digikey you can specify ranges for the parameters you are interested in before saving the search "address" and/or the table.  eg surface mount NPN Vceo 40-120V, Ic 10-50 A, ...

Comment: Back in the 1970s such a thing was possible. Today it would be too big and contain too much that isn't of interest or is already obsolete, like a phone book for the EU. Filtering a distributor's website like digikey or farnell is the right way to go now.